# Is there any way to hibernate netbeans session?

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins, ide

My ubuntu does not hibernate. Is there any way to hibernate/deep sleep Netbeans session so that it is possible to retain "undo/redo" data or unsaved file changes for next netbeans session after system shutdown?

Comment: Why does your Ubuntu not Hibernate? Have you tried addressing that issue?

Comment: Yes, I tried hard but it didn't not work so wondering whther this is something made possible by someone.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo pm-hibernate` from a terminal?

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't allot space for swap during installation?

Comment: yes tried `sudo pm-hibernate` & that did not successfully hibernated.. i needed to reboot my machine using CPU power button. I did not work with ubuntu 12.04 on my system & also does not work right now when I've upgraded to 14.04. 4 GB  swap space is already configured.. however separate swap partition is not there if that matters.. I guess I am using dynamically sized file for  swap.

Comment: Could you clarify whether this may be due to having swap file instead of dedicated swap partition ?

Comment: I am not entirely sure about that. AFAIK, they're quite interchangeable.